# How to get unique path for Unzip folder on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

On iOS:

How to fix this entire problume of unziping file, getting uniqe path name, use this path in other views  and deleting catch files once view did unload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to use the timestamp, store it in NSUserDefaults.

On applicationWillTerminate method of your AppDelegate, you check if NSUserDefaults has the key you set, if it have, then you delete the file, and remove the key.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"KEY_FOR_PATH"] != nil)
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"KEY_FOR_PATH"] error:nil];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"KEY_FOR_PATH"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

Comment: For most apps, `applicationWillTerminate:` is never called. That's not a good place to put much code.

Comment: So, maybe check if there is a file on application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I think this is not the best idea, but will work! Or put on viewcontroller's dealloc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique temporary directory using `mkdtmp` (declared in `unistd.h`), then expand to that dir.

Then if you need it someplace more specific, move *safely* (e.g. in a way that is guaranteed not to replace existing files/directories). `-[NSFileManager replaceItemAtURL:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:error:]` seems capable of the move, if you prefer a Foundation API.